# Not able to build query for Elasticsearch using java api

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Am trying to query elasticsearch via java api for the below elasticsearch query

```
get my_index12/_search {
        "query" : {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "code": {
                             "query": "TE-7000-8002-W",
                             "operator": "and"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "locale": {
                             "query": "en_US",
                             "operator": "and"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
     }
```

The above query is working fine is Kibana. Am trying to replicate the same query using Elasticsearch Java API.

Please find my JAVA API query that am trying to build.

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("code",name)).operator(Operator.AND);
```

Am getting the below error from eclipse.

```
The method operator(Operator) is undefined for the type BoolQueryBuilder
```

Am using Elasticsearch 6.2.3 version

Comment: `must` by default does boolean AND, do you explicitly need to specify it again?

Answer (score 0):

In java transport client, search request can be build both in QueryBuilders and XContent format which build query param in json format.
With QueryBuilder, especially BoolQuery, the operator in query dsl is represented by either must() (means and operator) or should() (means or operator).

As described, your query can be represented like:

```
QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must().must().build();
```

One more interesting question is how to present the following query DSL:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "term": {
                    "field1": "value"
                }
            }, {
                "match": {
                    "filed2": "value"
                }
            }],
            "should": [{
                "term": {
                    "field3": "value"
                }
            },{
                "term": {
                    "field4": "value"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

once you can understand the demo query DSL and successfully implement it with java API, means you are getting to know Java Transport client API.
hope can offer you some help